# How To Recreate Xero's Asset Depreciation Schedule

Tags: xero-api, xero

We are attempting to recreate Xero's asset depreciation schedule from scratch using information available from the Xero API.

The main problem that we are facing is that the depreciation rate can change during the lifetime of an asset. Because of this using the mathematical method to calculate depreciation prior to the change of the depreciation rate will be incorrect as through the assets API we have no access to historic depreciation rates.

It's clear that Xero is just summing over their automatically created depreciation journals but the lack of information that is retrieved on the journals endpoint means we have not found a way to link these journals to the corresponding asset.

Questions

1. In general how do we recreate the asset depreciation?
2. How can we link automatically created depreciation journals to their corresponding asset through the api?
3. How can we access historic depreciation rates?